# Pointer to char

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, pointers

Here's a snippet:

```
void addproductInterface(Tsklep **head){
    char* name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    double price;
    do{
        printf("Name: ");
        scanf("%s[^\n]", name);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nPrice: ");
        scanf("%lf", &price);
        fflush(stdin);
        addProduct(&(*head), name, price);
    } while(prompt("Do you want to add another one?"));
```

it works, but after I add **another** product, it changes the previous one (and the previous ones) to this name. 
It seems, that I pass **the same pointer** every time and I just change an array (when I add another product) it points to.
do I understand it correctly?
Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: can you please provide `addProduct` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the allocation of what `name` points to into the loop.

Comment: thank you, now working.. what about memory leak? Should I use free?

Comment: @TomDavies92: This depends on what `addProduct()` does. Does it copy the content of `name`?

Comment: it's just setting the new element and adds to the list, 
product->name = name; // name passed from addProduct(&(*head), name, price);

Comment: oh, I used crtdbg.h to detect memory leaks, there are in this place (where I use malloc to the name). How to fix it? I tried using free(), but it's not working ;/

Comment: @TomDavies92: So it would be bad idea to free the memory allocated in the while-loop as you keep arefernce to it.

Comment: Fixed the memory leak -> I copy name in addProduct, then I can use free() in do..while(). I updated my cleaning function, I added free(product->name) and it's working now :)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what you describe, yes. It's hard to tell for sure without seeing the code for `addProduct()`, but that would be the place to allocate new memory.

You should use a temporary, automatic (on stack), buffer for the input, then do the permanent allocation when you store the record, in `addProduct()`:

```
do{
    char name[64];
    double price;

    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("%63s", name);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nPrice: ");
    scanf("%lf", &price);
    fflush(stdin);
    addProduct(&(*head), name, price);
} while(prompt("Do you want to add another one?"));
```

You should also error-check the `scanf()` calls, they can fail if given unexpected input.

Also, [don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Answer (score 2):

You allocate the name only once, at the beginning of the function, so you overwrite the content on each loop execution. Move the allocation in do-while cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Move the line `char* name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);` inside the `do while` loop as follows,

```
do{
    char* name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("%s[^\n]", name);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nPrice: ");
    scanf("%lf", &price);
    fflush(stdin);
    addProduct(&(*head), name, price);
} while(prompt("Do you want to add another one?"));
```

Comment: -1, this can't possibly be right. If `addProduct()` is retaining the `name` pointer as it seems, this will `free()` the memory making the stored pointer invalid.

Comment: This is a good answer, but you should remove the call to `free`, it's harmful here: From the problem, it's clear `addProduct` does not duplicate the buffer, but instead keeps a pointer to it inside each `Tsklep` structure.

Comment: and btw. I write in strict C - I can't define variables wherever I want :/

Comment: Is it still wrong? If you want you could edit my answer and remove the down votee :)

Answer (score 1):

You should move your allocation inside the loop.

(by the way, your call to scanf is susceptible to overflow `name` since you don't limit the size.)